# Firewall blocking ssh out from a openVz container

Tags: linux, iptables, firewall, vps, openvz

I'm using a firewall on the HN to open/close the ports of the containers directly from the HN. I'm using the iptables script from the [openvz wiki](http://openvz.org/Setting_up_an_iptables_firewall).

Everything works fine but I cannot ssh out from the VPS. I can enter via ssh into the container, but if I try to do an ssh connection from the VPS to another server the firewall blocks it.

What rules should I add the the iptables script to allow the outgoing ssh connection?
Here's the script:

```
#!/bin/sh
# firewall      Start iptables firewall
# chkconfig: 2345 97 87
# description:  Starts, stops and saves iptables firewall
# This script sets up the firewall for the INPUT chain (which is for
# the HN itself) and then processes the config files under
# /etc/firewall.d to set up additional rules in the FORWARD chain
# to allow access to containers' services.
# http://wiki.openvz.org/Setting_up_an_iptables_firewall

. /etc/init.d/functions

# the IP block allocated to this server
SEGMENT="192.168.0.0/24"
# the IP used by the hosting server itself
THISHOST="192.168.0.1"
# services that should be allowed to the HN;
# services for containers are configured in /etc/firewall.d/*
OKPORTS="53"
# hosts allowed full access through the firewall,
# to all containers and to this server
DMZS="12.34.56.78 90.123.45.67"

purge() {
  echo -n "Firewall: Purging and allowing all traffic"
  iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT
  iptables -P FORWARD ACCEPT
  iptables -P INPUT ACCEPT
  iptables -F
  success ; echo
}

setup() {
  echo -n "Firewall: Setting default policies to DROP"
  iptables -P INPUT DROP
  iptables -P FORWARD DROP
  iptables -I INPUT   -j ACCEPT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED
  iptables -I FORWARD -j ACCEPT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED
  iptables -I INPUT -j ACCEPT -i lo
  iptables -I FORWARD -j ACCEPT --source $SEGMENT
  success ; echo

  echo "Firewall: Allowing access to HN"
  for port in $OKPORTS ; do
    echo -n "          port $port"
    iptables -I INPUT -j ACCEPT -s $SEGMENT -d $THISHOST --protocol tcp --destination-port $port
    iptables -I INPUT -j ACCEPT -s $SEGMENT -d $THISHOST --protocol udp --destination-port $port
    success ; echo
  done
  for ip in $DMZS ; do
    echo -n "          DMZ $ip"
    iptables -I INPUT   -i eth0 -j ACCEPT -s $ip
    iptables -I FORWARD -i eth0 -j ACCEPT -s $ip
    success ; echo
  done

  CTSETUPS=`echo /etc/firewall.d/*`
  if [ "$CTSETUPS" != "/etc/firewall.d/*" ] ; then
  echo "Firewall: Setting up container firewalls"
  for i in $CTSETUPS ; do
    . $i
    echo -n "          $CTNAME CT$CTID"
    if [ -n "$BANNED" ]; then
      for source in $BANNED ;  do iptables -I FORWARD -j DROP --destination $CTIP --source $source ; done
    fi
    if [ -n "$OPENPORTS" ]; then
      for port in $OPENPORTS ; do iptables -I FORWARD -j ACCEPT --protocol tcp --destination $CTIP --destination-port $port ; done
      for port in $OPENPORTS ; do iptables -I FORWARD -j ACCEPT --protocol udp --destination $CTIP --destination-port $port ; done
    fi
    if [ -n "$DMZS" ]; then
      for source in $DMZS ; do iptables -I FORWARD -j ACCEPT --protocol tcp --destination $CTIP --source $source ; done
      for source in $DMZS ; do iptables -I FORWARD -j ACCEPT --protocol udp --destination $CTIP --source $source ; done
    fi
    [ $? -eq 0 ] && success || failure
    echo
  done
  fi
}

case "$1" in
  start)
    echo "Starting firewall..."
    purge
    setup
    ;;
  stop)
    echo "Stopping firewall..."
    purge
    ;;
  restart)
    $0 stop
    $0 start
    ;;
  status)
    iptables -n -L
    ;;
  *)
    echo "Usage: $0 <start|stop|restart|status>"
    ;;
esac
```

And this is an example of the single container configuration which gets parsed from the firewall script.

```
# This file is processed by /etc/init.d/firewall
CTID="1"            # the container's ID#
CTNAME="Customer1"      # A human-friendly label for the container
CTIP="192.168.1.34"     # the IP address for this container 
OPENPORTS="80 443 22"       # ports that should be universally opened
                # to the entire Internet
DMZS="1.2.3.0/24 5.6.7.8/32"    # IPs and blocks that should have full access
                # to the container's services
BANNED=""           # IPs and blocks that should be entirely
                # blocked from the container's services
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that you can solve this problem by creating another file in `/etc/firewall.d/` and abusing $CTIP and $DMZS. You just turn them around, making $DMZS the IP of the container and $CTIP the Internet: `CTIP=0/0`

Comment: Nice workaround!